# How can I have an optional header row when reading a CSV file?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I need to import a CSV file that may or may not have a header record.

If I read a file that doesn't have a header row it assumes the first data row is the header and doesn't return it. 
If I specify HasHeaderRecord = false it will throw an exception when there is a header record.

Is there a way to use the CsvHelper library and have an optional header record?

I can get this to work using this approach, but it seems like there could be a better way:

```
csvReader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;

while (csvReader.Read())
{
    try
    {
        var record = csvReader.GetRecord<MyModel>();
        myRecordList.Add(record);
    }
    catch (ReaderException rex)
    {
        // Check if this is an error with no header record and ignore
        if (rex.ReadingContext.CurrentIndex == 1 &&
            rex.ReadingContext.RawRecord.ToLower().Contains("myHeaderColumnName"))
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it does bypass throwing an exception.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
    using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();

        if (!csv.Context.HeaderRecord.Contains("myHeaderColumnName"))
        {
            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
            reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
        }

        var records = csv.GetRecords<MyModel>().ToList();                        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no built in way to know for the csvReader. There are two ways to know:

1. The information "Header row yes/no" is provided by the user.
2. You implement a detection logic yourself by reading the first few lines and check for a few properties. Eg. the content type of a few columns.

In my opinion the information should be user provided or the source of the file should meet a standard to always provide a header row or never provide a header row.

Comment: The [CSV standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) linked from Josh's page mentions that a header line is optional and in our case unfortunately we also can't force the users to provide it.