# Read CSV files without Header using CSVHelper

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I have a lot of CSV files without header and need to read it in **C#**. I manually added header to one of these files and with the following code using **CSVHelper** I can read the files and show them in a GridView.

Now my question is, how can I read these files without a header? Or how can I add a header (a new record) using **CSVHelper** in the first line?

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Festival> records;
        var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { Delimiter = ";" };
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"File8.csv"))
            using(var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
        {
            records = csv.GetRecords<Festival>().ToList();
        }
        
        dataGridView1.DataSource = records;
    }
```

Class

```
 public class Festival
{
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public string Start { get; set; }
    public int Lenght { get; set; }
    public string FilmName { get; set; }
    public float Rating { get; set; }
}
```

csv sample

```
Mi;22:15;110;A;8
Mi;19:00;106;B;8
Mi;19:15;97;C;8.2
```

Comment: You can tell it how to [map the columns](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/mapping-properties/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I have an optional header row when reading a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56180336/how-can-i-have-an-optional-header-row-when-reading-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add column-index mapping attributes to the target members:

```
public class Festival
{
    [Index(0)]
    public string Day { get; set; }

    [Index(1)]
    public string Start { get; set; }

    [Index(2)]
    public int Lenght { get; set; }

    [Index(3)]
    public string FilmName { get; set; }

    [Index(4)]
    public float Rating { get; set; }
}
```

And specify `HasHeaderRecord = false` in the config:

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { Delimiter = ";", HasHeaderRecord = false };
```

If modifying the target model isn't desirable, [implement a `ClassMap` instead](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/mapping-by-index/):

```
public sealed class FestivalMap : ClassMap<Festival>
{
    public FestivalMap()
    {
        Map(f => f.Day).Index(0);
        Map(f => f.Start).Index(1);
        Map(f => f.Lenght).Index(2);
        Map(f => f.FilmName).Index(3);
        Map(f => f.Rating).Index(4);
    }
}
```

And register it like this before fetching the records (you still need to specify `HasHeaderRecord = false` in the config):

```
csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<FestivalMap>();
records = csv.GetRecords<Festival>().ToList();
```

Comment: docs: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/